# Rules to avoid parents of same WIT type

Tags: azure-devops

I noticed that it sometimes happens that users select parents from the same type like
story-story, epic-epic, ...
According to this post: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/same-category-hierarchy-error-but-the-specified-wo/761057
It's highly recommended to avoid this, due to obvious reasons.

Is it possible to prevent this by default?
Like a rule: if WIT is changed & parent type equals WIT type --> error

Answer (score 0):

No there is no built-in way to setup rules over work item relationships.

The [options that are supported can be found here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/custom-rules?view=azure-devops).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Sure, but it's terribly hard to point to the docs that describe a feature that doesn't exist.